# programmatically (VBA) see if I have access to a folder

Tags: vba, filesystemobject

I am trying to read through folders on a drive to see which folders I have at least read access to. I have used the DIR function in MS Access VBA. Is there a more accurate way to determine if I have access. Below is how I am using DIR. Thanks

```
dim path as string 
dim HaveAccess as integer
path = "C:\temp\"
 If Dir(path) = "" Then
  HaveAccess = 1 'no access
 Else
  HaveAccess = 2 'i have access
 End if
```

Comment: You tagged [filesystemobject] but your code does not include any use of the Object and your question does not mention that you want to use the Object. Did you add the tag for any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

You could use FileSystemObject, but you could also use the intrinsic `GetAttr` method:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Const path As String = "c:\"
   Dim folder As String
   Dim att As Variant
   
   folder = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
   
   Do While folder <> ""
      If folder <> "." And folder <> ".." And (GetAttr(path & folder) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
         att = GetAttr(path & folder) And vbReadOnly
         If att = vbReadOnly Then Debug.Print folder & " - read only"
      End If
      
      folder = Dir()
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used your sub above and it acts like my code because it contains the Dir function (if I don't have access to the folder it returns ""). It works but I was trying to make sure there wasn't a better way than using DIR.

Comment: Using Dir isn't necessary.  The key line is taking a folder and giving it to `GetAttr` after which you can test if the folder is ReadOnly.

Comment: not using Dir, the getattr() returns 0 which is normal. I get that same value if I am testing on a folder I have access to as well as one that is access denied.